# Trying to prove an integral inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functions, definite-integrals

Let $f_s,f_l:(0,\infty) \mapsto {\mathbb R}$ be monotonic increasing functions with $f_s(x) \leq f_l(x)$ and let $x_s,x_l$ be the smallest positive roots of the equation $1-f_{s,l}(x)=0$ respectively (assuming they exist, are real and no double roots). Then I believe the following is true
$$ \int_0^{x_s} \frac{{\rm d}x}{\sqrt{1-f_s(x)}} \geq  \int_0^{x_l} \frac{{\rm d}x}{\sqrt{1-f_l(x)}}$$
and if it is true I would like to proof it.
I just don‘t know where to start.

Heuristically I think it is because the increase in integration interval $x_s \geq x_l$ outweights the decrease of the integrand values $$\frac{{\rm d}x}{\sqrt{1-f_s(x)}} \leq \frac{{\rm d}x}{\sqrt{1-f_l(x)}} \, .$$

Observe for small deviations $f_l = f_s + \delta f$ we have to first order for the RHS
$$ 
\int_0^{x_l} \frac{{\rm d}x}{\sqrt{1-f_s(x)}} \left( 1 + \frac{\delta f(x)}{2(1-f_s(x))} \right)
$$
and so this requires
$$
\int_{x_l}^{x_s} \frac{{\rm d}x}{\sqrt{1-f_s(x)}} \geq \int_0^{x_l} \frac{{\rm d}x}{\sqrt{1-f_s(x)}} \left(  \frac{\delta f(x)}{2(1-f_s(x))} \right) \, .
$$
Any suggestions?

**edit:** You are right! I was a bit optimistic and also found a counterexample: Choosing $f_l(x)$ to become very close to $1$ very quickly and then only increasing slowly for a large interval makes the $f_l$ integral very large. On the other hand one can choose $f_s(x)$ negative and large enough, so that the integral for $f_s$ is very small. $f_s$ then increases just before $x_l$ to unity at $x_s=x_l$. This contribution should be small in comparison when the interval is large enough.

Comment: How is the rhs divergent for $f_l(x)=1-x^2$?

Comment: Oops, you're right. Deleting. Sorry.

Comment: Divergent integrals can not occur if $f$ is continuous and as mentioned no double roots occur.

Comment: Ah, I think I meant $f_l(x)\approx1-(1-x)^2$ for $x\le1$. Then $\int_0^1{dx\over\sqrt{1-f_l(x)}}\approx\int_0^1{dx\over1-x}=\infty$.

Comment: By "$\approx$" I mean replace the $2$ in $1-(1-x)^2$ with something slightly less than $2$. This eliminates the double root but keeps the integral as large as you want.

Comment: Yes, but that is a double root ;)

Comment: Ah, ok but i still mean that the roots are simple.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a counterexample with polynomials:

Let $f_l(x)={1\over2}(x+x^2-x^3+x^4)$ and $f_s(x)=x^2$.  We need to check that $f_l$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$ and that $f_l(x)\ge f_s(x)$ for $x\in[0,\infty)$.  Once we do that, it's clear that $x_l=x_s=1$, so that $\int_0^{x_s}{dx\over\sqrt{1-f_s(x)}}\lt\int_0^{x_l}{dx\over\sqrt{1-f_l(x)}}$.

To show that $f_l(x)={1\over2}(x+x^2-x^3+x^4)$ is increasing, we take the first two derivatives:

$$f_l'(x)={1\over2}(1+2x-3x^2+4x^3)\\
f_l''(x)={1\over2}(2-6x+12x^2)=1-3x+6x^2$$

Since $3^2-4\cdot1\cdot6=-15\lt0$, the second derivative is never $0$, hence, since $f_l''(0)=1$, it's always positive. This implies the first derivative is always increasing, so, since $f'(0)={1\over2}$, the first derivative is positive for $x\ge0$. This in turn implies the function $f_l$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$.

To show that $f_l(x)\ge f_s(x)$ for $x\in[0,\infty)$, we see that

$$f_l(x)-f_s(x)={1\over2}(x-x^2-x^3+x^4)={1\over2}x(1-x)^2(1+x)\ge0$$

Just for fun, the integrals are

$$\int_0^1{dx\over\sqrt{1-{1\over2}(x+x^2-x^3+x^4)}}\approx1.62868$$

(according to Wolfram Alpha) and

$$\int_0^1{dx\over\sqrt{1-x^2}}={\pi\over2}\approx1.5708$$

Finally, if you want an example with $x_s\gt x_l$, you can take $f_s(x)=(28x/29)^2$, in which case

$$\int_0^{29/28}{dx\over\sqrt{1-\left(28x\over29\right)^2}}={29\pi\over56}\approx1.6269$$

Answer (score 1):

Define $f_s(x) = x-1,$  $f_l(x)=(x-1)/2$ for $x\in [0,1],$ $f_l(x)=2(x-1)$ for $x>1.$ We then have $x_s=x_l =1.$ However

$$ \int_0^{x_s} \frac{{\rm d}x}{\sqrt{1-f_s(x)}} <  \int_0^{x_l} \frac{{\rm d}x}{\sqrt{1-f_l(x)}}.$$